# Install a version greater than or equal to of a package

Tags: debian, deb, debian-based

When I ran dpkg-checkbuilddeps on downloaded source code gcc-4.9 package I received below information:

```
# apt-get source gcc-4.9
# cd gcc-4.9-4.9.2
#dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32gcc1 libc6-dev-x32 libx32gcc1 libc6-dbg autoconf2.64 autogen gawk zlib1g-dev systemtap-sdt-dev gperf (>= 3.0.1) bison (>= 1:2.3) flex gdb locales sharutils libantlr-java libffi-dev fastjar libmagic-dev libecj-java (>= 3.3.0-2) zip libasound2-dev libxtst-dev libxt-dev libgtk2.0-dev (>= 2.4.4-2) libart-2.0-dev libcairo2-dev libcloog-isl-dev (>= 0.18) libmpc-dev (>= 1.0) libmpfr-dev (>= 3.0.0-9~) libgmp-dev (>= 2:5.0.1~) dejagnu realpath (>= 1.9.12) chrpath quilt doxygen (>= 1.7.2) graphviz (>= 2.2) ghostscript texlive-latex-base xsltproc libxml2-utils docbook-xsl-ns

Now I am trying to install gperf version (>= 3.0.1) - but none of the below commands works. How can I install a package with a version greater than or euqall to one specified in command line:

# apt-get install gperf='>=3.0.1'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gperf=>
# apt-get install gperf=3.0.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.0.1' for 'gperf' was not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current builds in debian repo should all be >3.0.1, lowest being [wheezy with 3.0.3-1](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gperf).

With `apt-cache show gperf | grep -i version` you get a list of versions currently known to your package manager. Maybe you need to add another repo?

Comment: Is it that the same reason my command apt-get install gperf=3.0.1 is failing cause the version itself is not there - also had it be there then the command would have worked - right?

Comment: @Prakash That's right, the command `apt-get install <package>=<version>` would be correct. But note here to use an actual version.
As example: `apt-get install gperf=3.0.4` would fail since the version name for jessie would be `3.0.4-1` or for stretch `3.0.4-2`

Comment: Sorry but though off topic - can you please explain "version name for jessie"  - could not understand this?

Comment: @Prakash each debian repo may host a different version, see [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases) for debian versioning. with 'version name' i meant the full version description of the package, like `3.0.4-1` since `3.0.4` is not an actual version.